# Postgresql and django - Unix domain socket

Tags: django, postgresql

i spend couple of hours to solve these problem but did not reach anything. There are several topics about this problem on the net but none of them says an absolute thing to solve this.

I just installed postgresql in order to use it on my django project.

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2", # Add "postgresql_psycopg2", "postgresql", "mysql", "sqlite3" or "oracle".
        "NAME": "name",                       # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        "USER": "postgres",                             # Not used with sqlite3.
        "PASSWORD": "pass",                         # Not used with sqlite3.
        "HOST": "",                             # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        "PORT": "",                             # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

this is my settings.py and the error is that

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Did anyone have a solution about it  ?

Comment: Why your 'HOST' and 'PORT' are empty? If you running your django server locally, then you must specify at least 'HOST':'localhost'

Comment: What's your system and version? How did you install Postgresql - from source, from distribution package or from installer? Did you check that Postgres service is really running? Where is Postgres socket - `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432` or `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` or in some other place. Are you able to connect using `psql`. For a couple of hours of work you don't provide much information to work on.

Comment: Debian 6 . host and port is empty because i'm on localhost no need to fill it

Comment: postgresql is running no problem . there's no directory /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 and tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 . My postgresql is under opt directory

Comment: Can it be that the unix-domain socket is located in another directory (eg /tmp/) You can point the host (-h) flag to this *directory* instead of a hostname. BTW: /tmp/ is the *default* location for the socket; but some distribution packagers have chosen to put it somewhere else. *sigh*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to locate a postgres socket. Check main postgres process pid (`ps auxw | grep postgres`) and list its open unix sockets (`lsof -p [PID_OF_POSTGRES_PROCESS] | grep unix`). Write this path to `HOST` option in `settings.py`.

Installing Postgres from distribution package (`apt-get install postgresql`) would be much easier (for example empty HOST in `settings.py` would work) and safer as your distribution will install security updates for you.

Comment: Also, as an alternative to `lsof`, the standard way would be to simply look up the `unix_socket_directory` entry of the `postgresql.conf` server configuration file.

Comment: thank you. It works. apt-get install postgresql installs older versions of postgresql . What i did is that i just installed 9.1 from the official site. apt-get install postgresql locates where django host but manuel install install it in a different directory.

Comment: The need for the newest version is a common problem that most administrators prefer to handle by using [backports](http://backports-master.debian.org/). Among other benefits like automated upgrades, a backport of 9.1 would have avoided the library/server mismatch on paths that you had to resolve here.

Answer (score 12):

Here's another possibility: if you installed a new version of PostgreSQL over an existing version, the installer might have assigned it a non-standard port number.

Django expects PostgreSQL to listen on port 5432. Even if you're using Unix sockets, the socket is named after the port number so this still matters!

Check `/etc/postgresql/<version>/main/postgresql.conf` for the line `port = nnnn`. If that number is not 5432, then that's your problem. Another indicator is that your socket file in `/var/run/postgresql` will be called something like `.s.PGSQL.5433`, using the non-standard port number.

To fix it, you can either edit the port number in `postgresql.conf` to use the default (5432), or if you need it to run on a non-standard port number, then set `DATABASE_PORT = 'nnnn'` in your django `settings.py`.

Thanks to [Erik Forsberg](http://efod.se/blog/archive/2010/02/06/pscopg2-operationalerror) for the pointer!

Answer (score 2):

On contemporary Fedora systems, a private temp directory feature has been added that will cause this symptom. https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ServicesPrivateTmp

This feature causes web apps to use a tmp directory different from the system /tmp directory where the default PostgreSQL domain socked is located.

To change the systemd directive for this feature for Apache-httpd on Fedora, edit the file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service` and change `PrivateTmp=true` to `PrivateTmp=false`

Alternatively, you can avoid using domain sockets to avoid this issue.